# the point of autocomplete attribute in html forms

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete

I know what autocomplete attribute is and how to use it, but I don't get the point of it!
I mean, why should I set autocomplete='off' as a developer?
Is there any security benefits in there? or something?

Comment: go to a login page.... hit down arrow on username field and pick a user because the developer did't turn off autocomplete. now 50% job is done and only have to figure out the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a security feature. Imagine this scenario:

Your website fell victim to a XSS attack (e.g. somebody was able to implant a piece of javascript in your page without your knowledge)

Your website also has username/password fields, and when a user enters the page, the malicious script immediately takes the values and sends them off to the attacker's server.

Granted, this is *not strictly mitigated* by disabling auto-complete, but at least it prevents userdata from being stolen just by somebody with saved data loading the page. It requires them to at least type in their credentials.

Also there is the rather obvious component of somebody gaining physical access to your machine and then being able to auto-complete their way into your accounts.